# Why does Firestarter say my firewall is active but ufw status shows it as inactive?

Tags: firewall

I am using Linux Mint and am having the following issue. Firestarter tells my that my firewall is active and it does indeed seem to be active. However when I type "sudo ufw status" into the terminal, I get the response "Status: inactive". It is my understanding that Firestarter is merely a way of controlling ufw. So, why the discrepancy?

Comment: Aren't they different programs? I know they are both firewalls, but  surely if you have Firestarter enabled and active, ufw won't know anything about if Firestarter is active or not?

Answer (score 3):

Both Firestarter and ufw are front-ends for [iptables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables). My understanding is that Firestarter hasn't been developed in some time and is quite buggy (last stable release in [January 2005](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firestarter_%28firewall%29)). If you are running both, one is likely conflicting with the other. I would uninstall Firestarter and use ufw. It is more reliable and under active development.